# Rationality of plane curves with a certain property

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C\subset\mathbb{C}^2$ be an irreducible algebraic curve defined over a number field $F.$ Suppose that for any $(z, w)\in C, z\in \mathbb{\overline{Q}}, w\in\mathbb{\overline{Q}},$
either $z\in F(w)$ or $w\in F(z)$. My question is whether such a curve $C$ must necessarily be rational? If $z\in F(w)$ for all but finitely many $(z, w),$ then $C$ is easily seen to be rational by Faltings' theorem.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  Much more is true: by Hilbert's Irreducibility Theorem, for each projection, the projection from $C$ to the affine line is birational.

Comment: Would you mind giving more details? Thanks!

Comment: I meant to write that at least one of the two projections is birational  (not necessarily both).

Comment: I still don't see how to arrive at that conclusion by Hilbert's irreducibility.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question.